# HTML / CSS : create a horizontal block list forcing width of the li elements

Tags: html, css, list

I have a horizontal list which is fine.
The image is shown below.[image]
The list right under the header is the list im talking about. What I want to achieve is basically you see each links wording is all in one line, e.g. "Mash's Famous Wings"
Well what im trying to do is create a fixed height and width (same for all) for all the li elements in the list. So this means that some of the words will go down into a new line.

See [Smokey Bones Menu Sub Navigation](http://smokeybones.com/menu/)as an example.

This is my CSS so far:

```
#menunavigation{
position:fixed;
top:100px;
left:50px;
z-index:1; 
color:white; 
}

#menunavigation a {
color:white; 
}


#menunavigation ul{
list-style-type:none;
height:50px;
}

#menunavigation ul li{
display:inline;
max-width:15px;
margin-right:5px; 
}
```

Comment: It might be better to add padding-left and padding-right instead of width for each <li> otherwise you'll get irregular spacing between each set of words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your css code with this snippet.

```
#menunavigation ul li
{
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:15px;
  margin-right:5px; 
}
```

however, `display:inline-block` will not work in IE-7, you need to include these extra lines, kind of hack which will work only in IE-7.

```
*display:inline;
*zoom:1;
```

or else if you are supporting IE-7 full time, you can detect it using [**contional comments.**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)